# Python: Optimise For loops using list-comprehension

Tags: python, optimization, list-comprehension

I have only recently started working with Python's list comprehensions. I am not comfortable with them. How would I optimise the code below by using list comprehensions?

```
heatmap_color = []

for r in xrange(len(heatmap)):
    heatmap_color.append([])
    for c in xrange(len(heatmap[r])):
        heatmap_color[r].append(cmap.to_rgba(heatmap[r][c], alpha=0.5, bytes=True))
```

What this code does is create a 2D array (representing a colour image's pixel values). The last line maps each one of the existing grayscale pixels in heatmap to a colour with an alpha channel = 0.5 so that these can be entered in the corresponding entry in the heatmap_color array.

Currently it takes just under 30 seconds to run. I would like to reduce this time as much as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nest the loops:

```
heatmap_color = [[cmap.to_rgba(r, alpha=0.5, bytes=True) for r in c] for c in heatmap]
```

Note that we don't need to use indices (generated by `xrange()`); loop *directly* over the lists instead.

You could use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) here too to speed things up a little more still:

```
from functools import partial
heatmap_rgba = partial(cmap.to_rgba, alpha=0.5, bytes=True)
heatmap_color = [map(heatmap_rgba, c) for c in heatmap]
```

or even:

```
from functools import partial
heatmap_rgba = partial(cmap.to_rgba, alpha=0.5, bytes=True)
heatmap_per_list = partial(map, heatmap_rgba)
heatmap_color = map(heatmap_per_list, heatmap)
```

because `map()` can be faster than list comprehensions, especially when used with `functools.partial` to avoid the extra stack-push a `lambda` would require.